# Filter python mysql result

Tags: python, mysql

I am running a mysql query from python using mysql.connector library as per code below

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=mysql_localhost, user=user, password=password, database=database)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("select  * from settings" )
results = cursor.fetchall()
ID, server, port, user, password, temp_min ,temp_max = results[0]
print(user)
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

the result is as follow

```
u'admin'
```

I noticed that values stored in the database as varchar display with u''
how can I get the value without the u'' so the desired output is

```
admin
```

Answer (score 1):

`u` means that this is a unicode string. You should read [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str()` to get rid of the `u`:

```
print str(user)
```

[FYI-the `u` means it is unicode.](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `u` in front of your variable means that it is a [unicode string](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). Is that really a problem? If you really need to convert it to a regular string you can use `str(user)`.